# Contents of zip file are truncated

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I want to write an XML string to a zip file using C#:

```
var myXmlString = "..."; // Contains some XML

// Set up zip archive
var archive = ZipFile.Open(FileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
var stream = archive.CreateEntry("myfile.xml").Open();
var sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

// Write data
sw.Write(myXmlString);

// Cleanup
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
archive.Dispose();
```

This works fine except for one detail: the text in the zipped file is truncated. So the XML is just cut off at one point. If I extract the .xml file from the zip, it is 7.171 Bytes large. The XML string I wrote into the file is 7.404 Bytes long.

Can anyone help me find out where the missing bytes went?

Comment: Why don't you close the streamwriter? That should flush and close the underlying stream.

Comment: Are just white spaces removed?  XML white spaces are optional and may be the reason the file is smaller.